# 2-Dimensional interval scheduling problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming, scheduling

I have a problem that is similar to the conventional interval scheduling algorithm but it is two dimensional, so I have another metric to take into account. My dataset format:

Cars with the **start and end time** of parking, along with their **length** in meters.
Total **street length** in meters.
**Number** of cars.
**Opening hours** of street parking.

Start and end times are in whole hours and length in whole meters.

I was thinking of splitting the street up into short 1 meter segments, but that wouldn't ensure a best solution as I wouldn't be able to optimize the locations based on later segments.

Objective:
The goal is to fit all cars in the street parking (Assumed possible). Output will be the location of the car during the given time period.

Comment: So can you clarify what exactly is your question?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to incorporate the length in the optimization process. The greedy algorithm is "1-dimensional", stacking those would work either. How could I "add" the length to a scheduling problem?